# Way to measure different degrees of a mental disorder?

Tags: mental-health, neurology, cognitive-science, measurement, disorders

Is it possible to have a disorder that might only display some of the symptoms, is not as defined, or episodic, making it "borderline"? Is there a way to measure, or at least express the severity of a mental disease?

Comment: Borderline with what? Mind clarifying the question with some background?